# How to set the cursor position with an X coordinate from input?

Tags: assembly, coordinates, x86-16, emu8086

Trying to set a value from input for coordinate *X*, but when I test the result, it seems that coordinate for *X* is random as it is showed at the bottom of CMD. How to pass an inputted value into DH register? It seems that not my desired value is passed but some random ASCII code.

```
mov ah,1;read value from input
int 21h
    
mov  dh,al;Trying to pass a value from input  x coordinate
mov  dl,10 ;y coordinate
mov  ah, 02h ;output
int  10h ;bios interruption
mov  al, '1' 
mov  ah, 0Eh
int  10h
mov dx,offset test
mov ah,9
int 21h
```

Here is example: inputted value 5 for *X*. Other numbers are just already set coordinates, like:

```
mov  dh,4
mov  dl,10
```

[image: Example in cmd]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The DOS.GetKey function 01h gives you an ASCII code in the AL register, eg. if the user presses <kbd>5</kbd> then AL will contain 53. If it's the value 5 that you're after, then simply subtract 48. Because the ASCII code for "0" is 48, you can write this conversion as `sub al, '0'`.

  ```
    mov  ah, 01h   ; DOS.GetKey
    int  21h       ; -> AL
    sub  al, 48
  ```
- The BIOS.SetCursorPosition function 02h expects from you the desired **column** in DL, the desired **row** in DH, and the displaypage to use in the BH register. You have omitted the BH from your code, and have **erroneously reversed the meaning of the DL and DH registers**. Also, when dealing with character output, we don't talk about *X* and *Y*, but rather about *Column* and *Row*.

  ```
    mov  dl, al    ; Column from input
    mov  dh, 10    ; Row
    mov  bh, 0     ; DisplayPage
    mov  ah, 02h   ; BIOS.SetCursorPosition
    int  10h
  ```
- The BIOS.Teletype function 0Eh additionally expects in BL the color to be used in case the display would be in a graphics mode, and in BH the displaypage to use. If the `Teletype` immediately follows the `SetCursorPosition`, you don't need to repeat setting BH.

  ```
    mov  bx, 0007h ; DisplayPage BH=0, GraphicsColor BL=7 (White)
    mov  ax, 0E31h ; BIOS.Teletype AH=0Eh, Character AL='1' (49)
    int  10h
  ```

Although the emu8086 emulator does not support the DisplayPage parameter in BH, you should learn and use the official BIOS api. Then at least your programs will have a chance when run outside of emu8086...

Comment: That's a great tip. I've learned the hard way that it's *always* a good idea to test your code on multiple emulators, since they're not always consistent in how they initialize the state of your environment. It'll show you very quickly if your code is making faulty assumptions about the register or memory state at bootup.

Answer (score 1):

You are reading a character from the standard input. You first need to convert it to a number:

```
mov ah,1 ;read value from input
int 21h
sub al, '0'
```